# Unfortunately google play store has stopped

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

[image]

I installed Android 6.0 on my one plus x phone last week. Now I see these errors pop up, "unfortunately google play store has stopped" & "unfortunately google play services has stopped". I searched so many websites but no use.  How can I fix this?

Comment: We need more information, how did you install the Google Play Services app? Was it flashed with a GAPPS archive or did it came pre-installed with the device? Tried to clear the data/cache of the Google Play Service and Google Play application?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a long time ago I had this issue. I'm sure there is an easier method of fixing it but I had to do a full factory reset before I could get it working again; hopefully you don't get to that point, but if you do give a factory reset a try :)

Answer (score -1):

go to apps, and disable Google+.  Reboot and it will work again

Comment: Mind to give some background? What has that specific app to do with it? Why should disabling it making the other app stable again?